# Cannot convert value of one type to another type

Tags: powershell

```
$printers = get-printer * | where { $_.Portname -like "*.ggg.com"} | Format-Table -Property Name -AutoSize 
foreach ($printer in $printers)
{
Remove-Printer -InputObject $printer
}
```

I have also tried `Remove-Printer -Name $printer.Name` and it does not work
Why am i getting this error :

```
Remove-Printer : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" value of type 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" to type 
"Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance[]".
At line:4 char:29
+ Remove-Printer -InputObject $printer
+                             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Printer], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Remove-Printer
```

Comment: remove the `| Format-Table ...` in your assignmen

Comment: as has been mentioned, the `F-T` is your problem. **_never use any of the `Format-*` cmdlets for anything other than FINAL output to the screen or a plain text file._** it _butchers your objects_ and wraps the bloody remains in formatting code. DO NOT use those cmdlets for anything other than what they are designed for.

Comment: Apart from the spot-on comments above. . . you don't need a loop, nor the asterisk in your code. You can pipe directly to `Remove-Printer`: `Get-Printer | where { $_.Portname -like "*.ggg.com"} | Remove-Printer`.